How to rig Anime Hair on a Dragon

Hi, can anyone tell me how I can create a kind of hair texture and then rig it onto my dragon so that I can animate the hair in a flying animation?
I've already tried with a particle system, but it didn't look like the hair in the picture. It should look like something from an anime.

Hello you can use curves then convert to mesh, and use the BoneDynamics addon to animate?

I will try it. But than i need to rig any hair strain on its own or?

you can rig several hair strain to one bone

this is a good idea

You have another addon called Wiggle Bones, you could also use Cloth physics

Several solutions:
You could use addons like Wiggle Bones or BoneDynamics that will simulate physics.
You could also use Cloth physics. First create a vertex group like that:

Give your object a Cloth physic, select the vertex group as Pin group, tweak the parameters, particularly the Stiffness:

Result:

An interesting solution that you could also test, explained in this video by RA Animation:
Give a Damped Track constraint to each bone of your bone chain (except first and last) with each time the next bone as Target and an Influence of 0.6 (more or less depending on the elasticity you want):

Result when you move or rotate the first bone (as stated in the comments to render "you need to bake the animated bones with that constraints first. after that, turn off the Damped Track, then render"):

